# 'ReactPlayer' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I attempt to use react-player for my React project. I'm using Typescript. I received the following error when I build it:

'ReactPlayer' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'ReactPlayer' is not a valid JSX element.
The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.
I suspect it is a specific to ReactPlayer. I probably mis-configure the project. Any help?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "home-exercise",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.67",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "flexbox-react": "^4.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-player": "^2.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
```

Comment: Showing us the `ReactPlayer` would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-river-38fcn?file=/src/App.tsx) based upon the [examples from the library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player).  I plugged in your `tsconfig` and everything appears to work.  Try comparing your project to that one.

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ReactPlayer url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Side note; I'd be very interested to see your `import` statement for `ReactPlayer`.  The error indicates you are not importing the thing you believe you are importing.

Comment: My import statement was "import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';". The project was bootstrapped by "npx create-react-app"

Comment: I can reproduce it by the following:
1. npx create-react-app demo --template typescript
2. yarn add react-player
3. use ReactPlayer.

This time, the error is 
```
'ReactPlayer' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'ReactPlayer' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'ReactPlayer' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.
```

Comment: I don't know what version of CRA you are using, but I just ran those commands and everything works with v4.0.0.  I used `npm` instead of `yarn`, though I find it unlikely that is what is causing the issue.  Going to need more information.

Comment: It turned out that removing "flexbox-react": "^4.4.0" fixes the issue. It looks like flexbox-react uses different version of react types which confuses typescript.

Comment: thanks @jackie1, i just spent 5 hours trying to figure out what was wrong with my code... turns out a child dependency of one my packages was using a different version of react types, which also solved the issue for me... wish I could give you an accepted answer

Comment: How did you figure out which dependency was causing this?